# In AEM 6.3 CFP2 are properties changed/removed no longer bubbling up?

Tags: aem

We have an event handler that was listening for component instance changes. We would capture the event, but while filtering out events that didn't have resourceAddedAttributes or resourceChangedAttributes set to certain fields in our components.

This event handler is now failing under AEM 6.3. I tried to refactor it into a ResourceChangeListener, but that's not working for us either. We can capture the event, however the addedPropertyNames and changedPropertyNames properties come back as null. It seems that AEM 6.3 is no longer bubbling up the names of what property of the resource changed.

Am I missing something or is this functionality that just no longer exists?

Comment: Those APIs were deprecated for some time now and I guess they "pulled the trigger" and removed them all together. I was implementing a `ResourceChangeListener` just yesterday (AEM 6.3 SP2) and saw the same behaviour.